# Use sed/grep/awk to delete everything up until the first blank line

Tags: sed, awk, grep

Can anyone help me figure out how to do this, it would be much appreciated.

example

```
block of            //delete
non-important text  //delete

important text      //keep
more important text //keep
```

Comment: Is the blank line empty, or can it contain whitespace?

Answer (score 10):

```
sed '1,/^$/d' file
```

or

```
awk '!$0{f=1;next}f{print}' file
```

#### Output

```
$ sed '1,/^$/d' <<< $'block of\nnon-important text\n\nimportant text\nmore important text'
important text
more important text

$ awk '!$0{f=1;next}f{print}' <<< $'block of\nnon-important text\n\nimportant text\nmore important text'
important text
more important text
```

Answer (score 6):

If the blank line is empty, this'll do it:

```
sed '1,/^$/d' filename
```

Comment: @SiegeX, *how* did I miss that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

with awk:

```
awk "BEGIN { x = 0 } /^$/ { x = 1} { if (x == 2) { print } ; if (x == 1) { x = 2 } }" filename
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to do something like: `awk '{if (initblock) print} /^$/ { initblock=1 }'` (which actually can be all on one line).  The `initblock` variable is initially zero.  The `if` action occurs on all lines, printing the input if `initblock` is not zero.  The `/^$/` pattern matches the empty line and sets `initblock=1` (meaning the initial block of lines to be deleted has been seen, and all remaining input will be passed through).  The pattern test occurs after the print so that the initial blank line is not printed.

Answer (score 0):

Another option with `grep` (working on lines)

```
grep -v PATTERN filename > newfilename
```

For example:

filename has the following lines:

```
this is not implicated but important text
this is not important text
this is important text he says
not important text he says
not this it is more important text
```

A filter of:

```
grep -v "not imp" filename > newfilename
```

would create newfilename with the following 3 lines:

```
this is not implicated but important text
this is important text he says
not this it is more important text
```

You would have to choose a PATTERN that would uniquely identify the lines you are trying to remove. If you use a PATTERN of `"important text"`, it would match all of the lines while `"not imp"` only matches the lines that have the words `"not imp"` in them.  Use `egrep` (or `grep -E`) for regexp filters if you want more flexibility in pattern matching.